# Show docstrings on every function call

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest, docstring

Let's say I have a code like this:

```
 class NewTestCase(unittest.TestCase, CommonMethods):

   def setUp(self):
      self.shortDescription()

   def test_01_sample test(self):
      """Testing something"""
      self.create_account(self.arg['account'])
      assert ...
   ...


 class CommonMethods():

   def create_account(self, account):
      """Creating account"""
      ...

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2, warnings='ignore')
```

I want to show the docstrings of all methods defined / created by me ('Testing something' and  'Creating account'), but the execution shows 'Testing something' only. Any tip?

Comment: Assuming `create_account` uses something like `len`, `str`, `print`, etc. Should their docstrings also be shown?

Comment: No. Only methods defined / created by me.

Comment: Guess you could write some sort of decorator that alters all the methods of the instance to print their docstring...

Comment: I thought that I could solve it using something simpler than that, but ok, your solution might be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an option for that in the `unittest` module, but I doubt it; otherwise, how would that module distinguish between *your* methods and functions and all sorts of library functions?

What you could do is to use another function to modify the existing functions to print their Docstring and/or other useful information whenever they are called. You could make this a decorator, or just call the function manually before running the tests.

This one should 'verbosify' all the methods of a given class (only slightly tested!), and you could make similar ones for individual functions or entire modules.

```
def verbosify(clazz):
    for name in dir(clazz):
        attr = getattr(clazz, name)
        if not name.startswith("__") and callable(attr):
            def attr_verbose(*args, **kwargs):
                print("Calling", name, args, kwargs)
                print(attr.__doc__)
                return attr(*args, **kwargs)
            setattr(clazz, name, attr_verbose)
```

Just call `verbosify(CommonMethods)` in your `main` block.